# After being a werewolf at night, how do I prevent becoming naked?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Every time I leave the beast form, it seems I'm naked and don't wear any of my clothes. Is there a way to not lose them after returning? Or should I become used to add my apparel to the favorites list?

Comment: Wear stretchy pants?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no way to prevent changing back naked. Unfortunately, you'll just have to put the clothes back on every time you transform.

Answer (score 2):

If you're playing on PC, you can use the [Werewolf Aftermath Re-Equipper](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/13905) mod, otherwise you will have to reequip your stuff after each transformation.